# Scheduling JobService to run only when app is running (on foreground)

Tags: android, jobservice

I need to do some background updates (about every 1 min). I have to use `JobService` to do it periodically. But I don't need to run service when app is closed - only when app is running (on foreground).

Is there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a JobService for that. Simply use normal Service. The OS allows apps in foreground to freely create the service. You can easily start a Service and perform your task. You can use `Handlerthread` for background processing or use `Handler` for foreground processing.

**Note for Android O:** If your app goes to background then your Service will be stopped as if you have called `stopSelf()`. Remember to clean up the necessary object's state.